# tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I was training an object detection model. While training the model I got this error :

```
" tensorflow : Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 463 batches)".
```

I have 5198 training images and 463 testing images. What values should I set for `'batch_size'`, `'steps_per_epoch'`, `'validation_steps'` and `'epochs'` for the model to train without errors?

[click to see the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muMQ9.png)

Comment: Please consider to write down your code in question itself instead of post it as an image.

Comment: @Masoud ,sure i'll keep it in mind next time